# Tomcat only allows two requests at the same time

Tags: gwt, tomcat

I have a GWT webapp, running under Tomcat, with the following remote service:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {

    @Override
    public void doIt() {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + this);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + this + " I have done waiting ");
    }
}
```

On my page I have a button, which, when clicked calls the service. The problem is, if I press the button two times, from three separate browser tabs, only the first two are executing, the third gets queued and executes as soon as one of the first two finishes. What should I modify to allow any number of requests to happen in the same time?

The connector in server.xml is:

```
 <Connector className="org.apache.catalina.connector.http.HttpConnector"
      port="8080" minProcessors="50" maxProcessors="75"
      enableLookups="true" redirectPort="8443"
      acceptCount="100" debug="0" connectionTimeout="160000"
      maxKeepAliveRequests="15"/>
```

Comment: which browser? can you try few others? there's a limit on the number of open connection a browser can keep with a server. RFC says "should not have more than 2", but i think it's more like 4-8 in the new ones.

Comment: And what happens if you try to connect with another browser while having these 2 open?

Comment: you could also try the non-blocking connector: protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"

Comment: @milan, you were right with the number of open connections a browser can have. It works if I connect from another browser, or from a different IE instance. Can you add it as an answer? I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a limit on the number of open connection a browser can keep with a server. RFC says "should not have more than 2", 2 for IE 6&7, but it could be more like 4-8 in the new ones. It's possible to configure IE to allow more: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=282402.

Comment: Thank you. I would have never pictured this as a browser issue.